# Opencart 2.0 Product Quantity add/minus not working

Tags: javascript, php, opencart2.x, q-query

I have a website, however the +/- buttons don't seem to work. I've not changed any of the code from the theme (Zorka), but I can't figure out how to fix the issue. Can someone please help?

Here's the website page: [Webiste](http://jccustomclothing.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=197)

The product.tpi looks like this:

```
              <div class="quantity-form form-group">
            <?php if (!$kuler->getSkinOption('show_number_quantity')) { ?>
              <button type="button" id="qty-dec" class="quantity__button">-</button>
              <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
              <button type="button" id="qty-inc" class="quantity__button">+</button>
            <?php } else { ?>
              <button type="button" id="qty-dec" class="quantity__button">-</button>
              <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" class="dynamic-number" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" data-min="<?php echo $minimum; ?>"/>
              <button type="button" id="qty-inc" class="quantity__button">+</button>
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
          </div>
```

and the product.js looks like this:

```
// Quantity
$('.dynamic-number').each(function () {
    var $input = $(this),
        $dec = $($input.data('dec')),
        $inc = $($input.data('inc')),
        min = $input.data('min');

    $dec.on('click', function () {
        var val = parseInt($input.val());

        if (val > min) {
            $input.val(val - 1);
        }
    });

    $inc.on('click', function () {
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    });
```

If you need more information, please let me know!

Comment: have you made another changes in code css?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No, not that I can recall. I actually have the original stylesheet.css at home so I can pop that back in this evening to see if that helps, but I really don't think I made any changes there so if you have any other ideas, i would be glad to hear them :)

Comment: So I've just uploaded the original stylesheet.css and nothing has changed, it still doesn't work.